# setenv.sh causing Tomcat7 to "fail" start

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

The problem is not as easy as it seems in the title.

I'm using a default Tomcat 7 package on Unbutu 14.04 LTS. When I have no "setenv.sh" in /usr/share/tomcat7/bin, it starts saying "OK" when I do :

```
$ sudo service tomcat7 start

 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7  [OK]
```

When I use the setenv.sh described below, it **ALSO STARTS** with no error in /var/lib/logs/catalina.out but the service is detected as "failed" when /etc/init.d/tomcat7 calls "start-stop-daemon --test" and concludes it's not running :

```
$ sudo service tomcat7 start

 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7  [fail]
```

What can I do about this ?

/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh :

```
#! /bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME="/home/linc/install/jdk1.7.0_75"
```

(...)

```
# Check for application specific parameters at startup
if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/appenv.sh" ]; then
. "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/appenv.sh"
fi
```

There is an other problem, maybe related : when I check the process running after the start detected as "failed" (`ps -ef | grep java`), I can see all -D options added by setenv.sh, but I can't see the -D option added by "appenv.sh" (though setenv.sh and appenv.sh have exactly the same 755 rights).

**Note** : if I launch `sudo /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh`, the setenv.sh doesn't cause any problem and appenv.sh is used.

EDIT : I may have found the cause but not the explanation : when I remove the declaration of JAVA_HOME, it uses the default jvm and the service start is detected as "OK", but when I specify the home of the default jvm , it fails again !

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre"
```

or :

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

What is happening here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the explanations.

The command testing wether the service is up or not excpects not only a PID but also a precise java binary :

```
start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
                            --user $TOMCAT7_USER --exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" \
                            >/dev/null;
```

This is run 2 times, one before "catalina.sh" (and setenv.sh) is run, one after.

The "standard" tomcat conf on ubuntu works like this : /etc/init.d/tomcat7 can be overrided by /etc/default/tomcat7 who can be overrided by catalina.sh (+ setenv.sh + appenv.sh).

So there are run with 2 different JAVA_HOME, first one with the one in /etc/default/tomcat7 or some auto-detected one, and second one with the one set in setenv.sh. This makes the start-stop-daemon test fail.

The solution would be to set JAVA_HOME twice, one in /etc/default/tomcat7 for the service launch, and one in setenv.sh in case some direct launch (via startup.sh in shell) needs to be done for test purpose, with some comments warning about the duplication.

About appenv.sh, the reason is CATALINA_BASE == CATLINA_HOME only when you start Tomcat from command line (startup.sh). When running Tomcat as a service CATALINA_BASE = /var/lib/tomcat7 while $CATALINA_HOME = /usr/share/tomcat7.

So putting setenv.sh (and appenv.sh) in /var/lib/tomcat7/bin/ instead of /usr/share/tomcat7/bin solve the problem.